# Communicate between browser extension and desktop app

Tags: javascript, java, operating-system, chromium

I'm trying to create a chromium program that is both web-based and also has access to the OS. Kinda like a browser extension but also does things that regular applications do, like altering system settings.

I'm stuck on trying to figure out how the program, written in **Java**, will connect to the **JS** part of it to control the system or vice versa. What's the best approach to this?

P.S. Fairly new programmer, so responses with external resources will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not possible for security reasons. Imagine the malicious code you could write if it could.

Comment: Okay, that makes sense.

Comment: It is possible if the Java program is executing on the machine with permissions to do what you want. Have the Java program run a web server that you can access from the browser with an address like `http://localhost:8080`. That would also get you way from needing a specific browser.

Comment: Maybe play with [Wasm](https://webassembly.org/). Note that it's still a virtual machine. Not a Java one though.

Comment: Wasm looks good @ElliottFrisch

Comment: Maybe you should look at native messaging host. You can communicate with extensions via your desktop application

Answer (score 0):

**One approach** is to make a 'local proxy' and listen on a specific port - so the browser part could talk with this port

**Another approach** is to write a simple app that would open a local port and listen to it (and go from there with different solutions)

edit:
or just set up a 'local web server and communicate with it (and on the web server part run local scripts/commands)

Answer (score 0):

You can use connectNative api [MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/runtime/connectNative) 
Chrome docs with example [native-messaging-client](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/apps/nativeMessaging/#native-messaging-client)